# Amazon MWS - Is it possible to reduce the order quantity using the OrderAdjustment feed

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I send an Order Adjustment feed such as

```
<MessageType>OrderAdjustment</MessageType>
<Message>
  <MessageID>1</MessageID>
  <OrderAdjustment>
    <AmazonOrderID>104-3121897-1466636</AmazonOrderID>
    <AdjustedItem>
       <AmazonOrderItemCode>42555034632370</AmazonOrderItemCode>
       <MerchantAdjustmentItemID>6174012</MerchantAdjustmentItemID>
       <AdjustmentReason>NoInventory</AdjustmentReason>
       <ItemPriceAdjustments>
         <Component>
           <Type>Principal</Type>
           <Amount currency="USD">0.15</Amount>
         </Component>
         <Component>
           <Type>Shipping</Type>
           <Amount currency="USD">0.50</Amount>
         </Component>
         <Component>
           <Type>Tax</Type>
           <Amount currency="USD">0.00</Amount>
         </Component>
       </ItemPriceAdjustments>
      <QuantityCancelled>1</QuantityCancelled>
    </AdjustedItem>
  </OrderAdjustment>
</Message>
```

it reduces the monetary amount of the order by the amounts in the feed, but does not change the order quantity, so the order still shows the original number of items as needing shipment.

According to the documentation, including the QuantityCancelled with an AdjustmentReason of NoInventory will create a partial cancel, but this does not seem to work.

Is there any way to reduce the quantity of items on an order?

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to find out from Amazon that as of Sep. 2010, it is not possible to reduce the quantity and have that change show up in the Seller Central user interface. They acknowledged this as a bug that may be fixed at some point in the future.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I tried the same sort of thing using "CustomerCancel", and even though the remaining items are flagged as "Shipped" in SellerCentral the order as a whole is never completed because the "CustomerCancel" line item is (*sigh*) still "Unshipped".

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still having this issue, I opened a case with amazon and after a few days I finally got a response from them:

> Partial cancellation of MFN orders is not supported by the system at this point. Either the order should be cancelled completely or completed and the unshipped items should be refunded.
>
> In order to completely cancel the order please use "_POST_FLAT_FILE_ACKNOWLEDGMENT_DATA_" for flat file or "_POST_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGMENT_DATA_" for XML feed.